# apply a constraint to summation limits

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a list as

```
list={{-0.5, 5}, {-0.25, 2}, {0, 3}, {0.25, 2}, {0.5, 5}}
```

and I want to use of `Esc+sum+Esc` symbol for summation in this format:
[image]

I mean this summation:

```
5*ee^-0.5x + 2*ee^-0.25x + 3 + ....
```

However we can use of `sum` but I mean Is it possible to use of constrains in lower limit and upper limit in the summation symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mathematica way is to write

```
Total[#2 Exp[# x] & @@@ list]
```

[image]

The same with the part of the list:

```
Total[#2 Exp[# x] & @@@ list[[2 ;; 4]]]
```

[image]

Also you can write an explicit sum with <kbd>Esc</kbd>sumt<kbd>Esc</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful and enjoyable,

Comment: As well as we can use of `Dimensions[list][[1]]` to upper limit of summation in the general case

Comment: @Bstates It is equivalent to `Length[list]`

Comment: Yes, Completely true